# How to variable deconstructing by using Spotify Web API

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to deconstruct two variables from the chained object.

```
const current = track.spotify.current.metrics.new_collection_listeners;
const previous = track.spotify.previous.metrics.new_collection_listeners;
```

I thought it would be possible to do something like this

```
const { current: new_collection_listeners } = track.spotify.current.metrics;
const { previous: new_collection_listeners } = track.spotify.previous.metrics;
```

But I got the error that the variable is already defined.

Then I thought it would be possible to do something like this:

```
const { current: { metrics: { new_collection_listeners }}} = track.spotify
const { previous: { metrics: { new_collection_listeners }}} = track.spotify
```

Or

```
const {
 previous: { metrics: { new_collection_listeners }},
 current: { metrics: { new_collection_listeners }},
} = track.spotify;
```

But it is saying that the `new_collection_listeners` is already defined and `previous` or `current` not.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: You are doing the destructuring in a wrong way, do it like, `const { new_collection_listeners: current } = track.spotify.current.metrics;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your attempts would declare `new_collection_listeners` **twice**. You need to "rename" the property to a unique name. This done using the `property: variableName` syntax:

```
const {
 previous: { metrics: { new_collection_listeners: previous }},
 //                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
 current: { metrics: { new_collection_listeners: current }},
 //.                                           ^^^^^^^^^
} = track.spotify;
```

I recommend to read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to learn more about the desutructuring syntax.

---

```
const { current: new_collection_listeners } = track.spotify.current.metrics;
const { previous: new_collection_listeners } = track.spotify.previous.metrics;
```

is the same as

```
const new_collection_listeners = track.spotify.current.metrics.current;
const new_collection_listeners = track.spotify.previous.metrics.previous;
```

---

```
const { current: { metrics: { new_collection_listeners }}} = track.spotify
const { previous: { metrics: { new_collection_listeners }}} = track.spotify
```

is the same as

```
const new_collection_listeners = track.spotify.current.metrics.new_collection_listeners;
const new_collection_listeners = track.spotify.previous.metrics.new_collection_listeners;
```

Comment: Thank You very much! Forgot about the last `property: variableName ` part :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const { current: new_collection_listeners } = track.spotify.current.metrics;
const { previous: new_collection_listeners } = track.spotify.previous.metrics;
```

would define the variable **new_collection_listeners** twice.

it should be

```
const { new_collection_listeners: current } = track.spotify.current.metrics;
const { new_collection_listeners: previous } = track.spotify.previous.metrics;
```

since it is defined like `property: variableName`. what you did was the opposite